# Tomcat keeps files locked - causes failing re-deployments

Tags: maven, tomcat

We are trying to use the Maven Tomcat plugin (https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/) to automatically deploy new versions of our application to a test server.

That works perfectly fine when deploying to a "fresh" Tomcat (or when one has previously manually removed an older version of our application by stopping Tomcat and removing the .war file plus the "exploded" application directory from the webapps directory and then restarting Tomcat again).

However, when I do a redeployment of a new version using the mentioned Maven plugin or manually via Tomcat's application manager ("upload war file") while Tomcat is running, then these redeployments always fail because Tomcat keeps two library jar-files of the previous version locked. Thus the removal of the old application version fails and as a consequence the subsequent redeployment of the new version is aborted leaving the application de-facto destroyed.

In the Tomcat log one can then always find the very precise error message:

```
...
24-Mar-2021 21:33:03.245 SEVERE [http-nio-80-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.deleteDir [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\wps\WEB-INF\lib] could not be completely deleted. The presence of the remaining files may cause problems
24-Mar-2021 21:33:03.256 SEVERE [http-nio-80-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.deleteDir [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\wps\WEB-INF] could not be completely deleted. The presence of the remaining files may cause problems
24-Mar-2021 21:33:03.306 SEVERE [http-nio-80-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.deleteDir [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\wps] could not be completely deleted. The presence of the remaining files may cause problems
24-Mar-2021 21:33:03.306 SEVERE [http-nio-80-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.delete [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\wps] could not be completely deleted. The presence of the remaining files may cause problems
...
```

So, the problem as such is pretty clear, but the question is: WHY does Tomcat keep these files locked? What could be causing this? Why can't it stop the processes/threads of the application that apparently use these .jar's so that these files can be successfully removed and the redeployment successfully continues?

The files that are kept locked are:
`spring-context-support-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar` and a .jar containing one of the modules of our own application (`wps-service.jar`).

Is there anything one can do to force the removal of such files? Or has anyone encountered this error before and found a fix or work-around? Or any idea what we might be doing wrong so that Tomcat can not stop that application?

We are using Tomcat v9.

Comment: Did you try `antiResourceLocking="true"` in the [`Context`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html) configuration?

Comment: @Piotr: thanks for responding. Yes - meanwhile I googled that and it indeed works. Although its not a beautiful solution (IMHO). You end up with an ever growing temp folder containing old versions (or parts thereof). Since this is a test server that might pile up and will require some cleanup from time to time. But at least our Jenkins can now automatically deploy to that server. But I am really puzzled about the root cause and how we could find out and if so, how we could fix this...