# Why do I get a ClassNotFoundException when redeploying a webapp on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I am developing a web app and deploying it to a local instance of Tomcat 9.0.73.

This works fine, but I occasionally get this error, and WAR deployment fails.

Why is that?

```
13-May-2023 10:14:03.042 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.73\webapps\ROOT.war]
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:686)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:662)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1023)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1910)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:577)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:824)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:474)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1617)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:318)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:898)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:795)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:249)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:917)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
        Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
                ... 35 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
                at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.StatusViaSLF4JLoggerFactory.addStatus(StatusViaSLF4JLoggerFactory.java:32)
                at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.StatusViaSLF4JLoggerFactory.addInfo(StatusViaSLF4JLoggerFactory.java:20)
                at ch.qos.logback.classic.servlet.LogbackServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(LogbackServletContainerInitializer.java:32)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4929)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                ... 36 more
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1412)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
                ... 41 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this happens when the previous version of the WAR could not be deleted. This is the warning Tomcat gives when deploying the WAR file. If the deployment is attempted again, it leads to the error above.

```
java.io.IOException: [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.73\webapps\ROOT] could not be completely deleted. The presence of the remaining files may cause problems
```

The fix is to delete the WAR and the webapp directory where it was installed when the warning message is displayed, before re-attempting deployment.

As for the reason why a WAR file may not get completely deleted: it seems to correlate with the app being open in a browser. So before redeploying an app, close all its pages in your browsers.

Alternatively, try setting `antiResourceLocking="true"` in the Context configuration, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66789403/tomcat-keeps-files-locked-causes-failing-re-deployments).